# Better way to create a tooltip in Altair

Tags: python, altair

Is there a better way to create this tooltip in Altair? It doesn't feel very python-esque. Can I avoid the repetition of the alt.Tooltip? ('coin' is a str, 'usdValue' is numeric).

```
            tooltip=[
                alt.Tooltip("coin"),
                alt.Tooltip("usdValue", format="$.3s", title="Valor"),
            ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to use `alt.Tooltip` on the fields where you want to change the default tooltip formatting:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()

alt.Chart(source).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    color='Origin',
    tooltip=[
        'Origin',
        alt.Tooltip('Horsepower', format="$.3s", title="Valor")
    ]
)
```

And just a reminder to [post a full minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with code and data for your next question.